# How to iterate over an Excel file and ID colored cell values

Tags: openpyxl

I have an excel workbook that has cells of a column colored with specific colors to keep or exclude certain users that will then be used to filter another excel workbook.

I want to loop through this column and identify cells with red background and add a functional column stating 0 and identify cells with yellow background and add 1 to this same functional column so as to work as the filter for the other workbook.

I'm hoping to use OpenPyXL to complete this task.

```
column_pi = ws["A"]

for cell in column_pi:
    f cell.fill.fgColor == "00FF0000": # Red Hex 
        # add column stating 0 as value
```

Have also tried this but no luck, returning nothing

```
red_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='00FF0000', end_color='00FF0000')
yellow_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='00FFFF00', end_color='00FFFF00')

for cell in column_pi:
    if cell.fill == yellow_fill:
        print(cell)
```

Works with no hex codes provided for `no_fill`

```
no_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None)

for cell in column_pi:
    if cell.fill == no_fill:
        print(cell)
```

Any thoughts on the best way to iterate over the values and check the fill/background color are of a specific color and then add a functional column like this?

Comment: You need to set the fill_type. Best check the details of a cell that you know has a fill.

Answer (score 1):

`fill` is a set of more complicated variables, so looking for it to be exactly equal only to `red_fill` or `yellow_fill` here isn't going to work. The complication is mostly due to being able to set a colour either as a static rgba value, or as one that will automatically update when the theme is changed. Styles in openpyxl, with parameters like PatternFill, are easy ways to set multiple of these values at once.

If you look up `cell.fill` for a particular cell, it returns something like:

```
<openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill object>
Parameters:
patternType='solid', fgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='FFD9D9D9', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb', bgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'
```

You can specify these values directly as part of `cell.fill.fill_type` (synonym for `cell.fill.patternType`), `cell.fill.fgColor`, and `cell.fill.bgColor`. Plus sub-attributes like `cell.fill.fgColor.rgb`.

You could also make it quicker by picking `knowncell.fill.fgColor` of a cell you know to have red_fill, if one exists. That way, you could check any of `fill_type`, `fgColor` and/or `bgColor` match. Try:

```
red_fill = knowncell.fill
for cell in column_pi:
    if cell.fill.fgColor == red_fill.fgColor and cell.fill.fill_type == red_fill.fill_type:
        print(cell)
```

However, you can't match `knowncell.fill` directly with `cell.fill`, I think because a new openpyxl style object is created each time you define a new one.

Comment: Actually, I think the problem would be the missing type: solid fills are a special case of pattern where the foreground (or is it the background?) isn't visible.

Comment: I'm just copying what was returned for a cell where I'd picked a light grey fill. I guess it implies it's the background that's not visible. But for whatever reason, when I set the fill of that cell to a variable, and then checked whether the variable == the fill of the same cell, it returned False.